# What does it mean when i say, in a Hologram, not only the intensity distribution but also the phase distribution is recorded?

Tags: laser

What is exactly meant by the phase distribution of the scattered wavefront? Does that mean the light reaching the recoding medium each would have a different phase **at the recording medium** depending on the position they're coming from on the object being holographed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The hologram records the waves reflected from an object that is illuminated with a coherent plane wave. Then both the reflected and rather complex wave and a reference sample of the illuminating coherent plane wave together are captured in a recoding medium. Since those waves are coherent *in time* with each other the recording is a stable interference pattern of the two.